# Apache: impedir redirecionamento SSL de uma URL específica

Tags: apache, ssl, https

Meu servidor (Apache 2x) está funcionando corretamente com certificado SSL porém preciso impedir que apenas **uma única URL** aceite conexão normal (somente HTTP).

A estrutura atual está assim (está bagunçado, devido a testes já realizados)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName domain.com
            ServerAlias www.domain.com

            #Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    RewriteEngine on
                    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
                    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                    RewriteCond $1 !^/complemento/url [NC]
                    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
        </IfModule>
            Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin domain@gmail.com
            ServerName domain.com
            ServerAlias www.domain.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /home/domain/domain.com.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /home/domain-bundle.crt

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

            <Directory /var/www/html>
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Desta forma não funciona. Como proceder?

Comment: Desculpe, mas eu não entendi exatamente quais URLs devem ser redirecionadas e quais não. Poderia exemplificar melhor, por favor?

Comment: @HenriqueMarti TODAS as URL's devem ser HTTPS. Apenas UMA deve ser normal (HTTP).

Comment: @HenriqueMarti sendo mais didático:
Qualquer URL do site www.example.com deverá ser HTTPS, mas a URL (e somente ela) www.example.com/url-especifica deverá ser normal (HTTPS)

Comment: Tente essas duas respostas: [resposa 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34084642/1377664) [resposta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456077/1377664)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira:

- Removi o redirecionamento do default-ssl.conf (Apache)
- Por se tratar de um sistema em CakePHP, editei o .htaccess dentro de /app/webroot e inseri o redirecionamento ali, ficando como abaixo

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
      RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/reports/producao_logs/add/[a-zA-Z0-9]+?$
      RewriteRule http://{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  ```

Tive que proceder desta forma pois as soluções anteriores estavam redirecionando para http://domain.com/**app/webroot**/endereco e, com isso, ele não reconhecia a regra e acabava jogando para o HTTPS novamente (além de gerar erro no próprio CakePHP).

Answer (score 2):

Veja este exemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/complemento/url/?$
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Onde:

- http://dominio/complemente/url, não será redirecionada para `HTTPS`
- http://dominio/complemente/url/, não será redirecionada para `HTTPS`
- Qualquer outra URL será redirecionada para `HTTPS`

Não há necessidade de utilizar o `Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/`

Comment: Aparentemente a solução funcionou, pois já consigo acessar sem o redirecionamento. Porém a página está retornando erro 404. O que pode ser?

Comment: `404` é que não encontrou conteúdo a ser exibido, exemplo, se o diretório que está usando é o padrão, verifique se existe um index em: `/var/www/html/complemento/url`

Comment: Sim, o caminho está correto. Tanto que quando acesso o mesmo endereço acrescido do HTTPS ele abre normal, mas quando removo o HTTPS, ele dá 404

Comment: Editei a resposta, estava faltando informar o `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações, mas ainda não consigo fazer funcionar direito. Agora está conflitando com o .htaccess do CakePHP e redirecionando o endereço para .../app/webroot/... e, então, adicionando o HTTPS novamente.